# Making material ui's Typography more efficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

Hello below i have the following typograohy code that has been replaced with examples but does represent my code, as you can see i have to call Typography a number of time and was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

```
<Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="title" >Main Details</Typography><Divider />
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example: </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >IExample:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example: </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
                    <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading" >Example:  </Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["Text1","Text2",...,"TextN"].map(x => {
       <Typography className = { classes.titleText } variant="subheading">{x}</Typography>
})
```

You can use the Array.prototype.map function to map each value to a result of a function.
So I took all the texts you have, which is in the array and mapped them each to the typography element with the text inside.

You can read all about it with examples in here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @double-beep Thank you, you're perfectly right. I've added some explanations.